# With Roxygen and testthat, what is the proper way to make internal helper functions available to testcases called during R CMD check?

Tags: r, roxygen2, testthat

I am creating an R package, and found it useful to break parts of the logic in one file into internal helper functions, which I define in the same file.  I have sort of a special case where my function decides which helper function to use via `match.fun()`.  Since they won't be useful to other functions or people, I don't want to put these in separate files, and I don't want to export them.

All my testthat cases pass using `test_dir()`.  When I don't export these functions, my testthat cases fail during R CMD check.

```
"object 'helperfunction1' of mode 'function' was not found", quote(get(as.character(FUN),
         mode = "function", envir = envir)))
```

After looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249673/how-should-i-handle-helper-functions-in-an-r-package), I am able to get things to work if I explicitly export or add export entries to NAMESPACE, but again I don't want to export these.

Is there a better way to do this and doesn't require me to export?  (I'll admit that the source of the issue may be `match.fun()` and am open to other ways of calling functions at runtime.)

Comment: Can't you just use `yourPackage:::helperfunction1(...` there? (Note, that these are 3 not 2 colons.)

Answer (score 1):

From memory it wasn't clear in the documentation last time I read it (it may have changed), but it will work correctly (without having to export) so long as everything is in the right directories:

You should have a file:

```
tests/run-all.R
```

That looks like:

```
library(testthat)
library(myPackage)

test_package("myPackage")
```

Then your individual test files should be in the directory `inst/tests`

These will be run when you do `R CMD check`, otherwise you can call `test_package("myPackage")` in `R` manually.

Comment: Yes I have that test runner, but in this case I'm not planning to make my tests available in the package, so they aren't in inst/tests.  Is there another way around this?  As of now my test runner (`tests/run-all.R`) looks like: 
`library(testthat)  
test_dir("testthat")`

Comment: I'm not sure. I just know that if the files are in `inst/tests` then you don't need to export the functions those tests rely on.