# How can I hide the documentation of helper functions?

Tags: r

I'm maintaining a package that has a number of helper functions documented with .rd files. As they are not exported, they are not easily accessible by users - this is good. However, they still show up in the index of package help files.

Is there a way to have documentation removed from the index so that it does not clutter it, but still accessible via `help`?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249673/how-should-i-handle-helper-functions-in-an-r-package) question? There is a comment how to hide the helper functions but not completely sure if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @drmariod Not quite. My problem isn't with visibility of functions themselves, rather that I want them to have standard documentation, but not appear in the index.

Comment: If you're using roxygen2 you can use `## ` instead of `#' ` and just comment it.

Comment: @TylerRinker I was hoping to have a way to still be able to access the documentation using `help`. It's not crucial however, and I might just either leave the index cluttered or go with your suggestion.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a field in the Rd file you can add called `keywords`. Most keywords don't do anything except help you search for functions with one notable exception: `internal`. Marking a function with the internal keyword removes it from the index. According to the [roxygen2 vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html):

> `@keywords keyword1 keyword2 ...` to add standardised keywords. Keywords are optional, but if present, must be taken from the predefined list replicated in the keywords vignette. Keywords are not very useful, except for `@keywords internal`. Using the internal keyword removes all functions in the associated .Rd file from the documentation index and disables some of their automated tests. A common use case is to both export a function (using `@export`) and marking it as internal. That way, advanced users can access a function that new users would be confused about if they were to see it in the index.

Adding `@keywords internal` to the roxygen comments will give the desired result.

Comment: In your last sentence it should be `@keywords`, not `@keyword`.  (Also, what's with not being able to offer an edit of less than 6 characters?  There are lots of times when an error of less than 6 characters in a program can have catastrophic results.)

Answer (score 1):

A little bump for people experiencing `@keywords internal` not working;

I made the mistake of mixing up `??PACKAGENAME` and `help(package="PACKAGENAME")`. Because of this I was left confused why I still saw the documentation of the internals. `??` loads ALL documentation of your package and is not neccesarily the user help index.

Very basic mistake, but there ya go.